# Record the start and end times of a command and store them in a CSV file

Tags: windows, datetime, batch-file, cmd, output

I have a batch file and I'd like to know how long it took to run then output the log file results in a .csv formatted file. Desired output would look something like this:

```
    Batch,Date,StartTime,EndTime
    AM,Sun 09/18/2016,07:00:00,07:53:42
    PM,Sun 09/18/2016,19:00:00,19:51:54
    AM,Mon 09/19/2016,07:01:22,07:56:54
```

The "Batch" column is just whether the script was run in the morning or night. with an outcome of either "AM" or "PM". I don't know how to do the conditional "if". But I was thinking something like:

```
    set startdate = %date%
    set starttime = %time%

    Don't know how to do if/then/else so in words:
    if starttime is less than 12:00:00, then set batch="AM". Else set batch ="PM"
```

Then at the end of my file I'd put:

```
    echo %batch%,%startdate%,%starttime%,%time% >> C:\backup_time.csv
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your entire title contains no information that can't be gleaned from the tags you've added, which gives it no meaning. Your title should be clear enough to have meaning  to future readers here who see it in a search result.

Comment: Sorry. New to this. I thought I did that. What would you suggest as my title? What tags?

Comment: Your *tags* are fine. Your title simply repeated them, which wasn't. It looks like @SomethingDark has already done the edit for you.

Comment: Ahhh... that's why I was confused. I was thinking that was a pretty good title. Don't recall what it was before now, but appreciate y'all steering me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Your title was literally "Windows Batch File (CMD)" - you can probably guess why it needed to be changed :)

Comment: Sheesh. I don't even remember typing that. But thank y'all for walking me through. Sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is next error in your code:

```
rem          ↓ ↓        harmful spaces
set startdate = %date%
set starttime = %time%
rem          ↑ ↑        harmful spaces
```

Next code snippet should work as expected:

```
set "startdate=%date%"
set "starttime=%time%"
set "_aux=%starttime:~0,2%"          extract hours from time
set "_aux=%_aux: =0%"                change possible leading space to zero if necessary
    rem treat properly values 08 and 09 using modulo operator in next `SET /A` command
set /A "_aux=1%_aux% %% 100"
if %_aux% LSS 12 (set "batch=AM") else set "batch=PM"
>>C:\backup_time.csv echo %batch%,%startdate%,%starttime%,%time%
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%starttime:~0,2%` etc.) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- (`>>` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- (`%_aux: =0%` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!